# How to test for live session variable and refresh via JavaScript if not live?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am using ColdFusion 8 and jQuery.

I have a page that uses a lot of ajax. When a button on the page is clicked, some data is sent to the CFC to retrieve data. The data retrieval requires session variables. If the page has sat unused for a while and the session has ended, the page creates an error.  The user can click all he wants but won't see the error because it's behind the scenes in ajax. Firebug shows me that the session variable no longer exists. Here's the error:

```
Element USERINFO.CATALOG_ID is undefined in SESSION.
```

At the top of my CFC, I move things from the APPLICATION and SESSION scopes to the VARIABLES scope like this:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cfscript>
    // DEFAULT DATASOURCE
    VARIABLES.DS = APPLICATION.Datasource;
    // SET CATALOG AND MARKET
        VARIABLES.Catalog_ID = SESSION.UserInfo.Catalog_ID;
    VARIABLES.CatalogType = THIS.getCatalogType(VARIABLES.Catalog_ID);
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name='SomeFunction>
    </cffunction>

<cfcomponent>
```

What is a good way to test if the session is still active and if not, return something to the page instructing it to refresh itself thereby restarting this session?

Comment: The way I've dealt with this in the past is to trigger an event on keypress, that is only called once every X minutes (shorter than your session timeout), from there I just call "emptyPage.cfm" which keeps the session alive as long as they're still typing/playing on the page.

Comment: Interesting... but in this case, it doesn't help. If the sessions dies, and then the user clicks a button, I need refresh the browser.

Comment: The way I have dealt with session timeouts in the past is similar to what @phantom42 is suggesting.  Return an error from the AJAX call and handle it appropriately for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to keep a session open I use a very small (1 pixel) iframe.  The page in the iframe simply does a meta refresh every x seconds and this keeps the session alive.

Having said that, it's rare that I want to keep a session alive.  They timeout for a reason.  We also incorporate a javasript countdown timer that directs the user to another page at about the same time the session times out.  In the scenario describe above, the user would not be able to click the button because it wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just ran into this problem with our own application. In our issue, we were dealing with REQUEST vars which were missing/empty due to the session timing out. Users would submit to a `cfgrid` and the edits would post with incorrect/missing data.

My solution was to check for the existence and for a properly set variable. If either fails, I return back a false/failure, otherwise normal processing continues and I return back a true/success.

In the CFC method:

```
<cfif NOT structkeyexists(session,"userid") OR len(trim(session.userid)) EQ 0>
  <cfreturn false>
</cfif>
<!--- normal processing --->
<cfreturn true>
```

Then in my callback handler in the main page, I handle the true/false returned. If it's failed, I pop up an alert message and reload the page, which auto-redirects the user back to the login page.

```
var myCallBackHandler = function(r) {
    if (r==true) {
      // normal success processing
    } else {
      // update failed - usually due to timeout
      alert('Your session has timed out. The data was NOT saved. Please log in and try again.') ;
      location.reload(true) ;               
    }           
};
```